# How to get query string using React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get "query=123" from the url http://localhost:3000/?query=123. Tried

```
//App.js
const search = this.props.location.search;
const params = new URLSearchParams(search);
const foo = params.get('foo');

console.log(this.props);
```

and my console shows this https://d.pr/i/w5tAYF
which doesn't show location.search anywhere... any idea how I would get the query string?

Comment: the reason is when i tried to log this.props.location, it's undefined. please check my image shown for this.props

Comment: `this.props.location.search` doesn't contain the query. You need to look in `window.location.search`.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

React doesn't handle URL search parameters. You need to look in the `window` object for them instead. Here's how you would get the value of `query`:

```
let search = window.location.search;
let params = new URLSearchParams(search);
let foo = params.get('query');
```

Comment: new URLSearchParams(search).get('foo') is not working for some reason

Comment: i'm getting null. here's a screenshot of const params https://d.pr/i/r5GcHM

Comment: You need to change it to `get('query')`. I was using `foo` as an example. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I created a separate function for the query string.

```
function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
}
```

Then I can provide the query string I want to get. In your case its `query`

```
  let query = useQuery().get('query');
```

Answer (score 3):

Within your component, you can do something like this:

```
const values = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
console.log(values.filter) 
console.log(values.origin)
```

There is more [here](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-query-strings/).

Comment: OP doesn't seem to be using React Router.

Answer (score 2):

```html
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const search = useLocation().search;
console.log('path', search);
const id = new URLSearchParams(search).get("id");
console.log(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get query params from a custom URL, not the currently opened URL, you can use the code below.

```
const customURL = 'https://custom.url.com?success=true'
const params = new URLSearchParams(customURL.split('?')[1])

const successParamValue = params.get('success')
```

If you are using **React Native** you will need additional step to support `URLSearchParams`. Just install below package. that's it!

```
npm install react-native-url-polyfill
```

or

```
yarn add react-native-url-polyfill
```